# Android Custom View's constructor is executed twice

Tags: java, android, view, constructor, duplicates

I have faced an issue after creating custom view class in android. The issue is simply, when I create an object of the custom view, its constructor is executed multiple times.

Code of the main Activity Class

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        CustomView customView = new CustomView(this, null);


    }


}
```

Code of the customView

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class CustomView extends View {


    public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        System.out.println("Custom View is executed");
    }



}
```

Code of main Activity's xml layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="4"
    tools:context=".MainActivity2">


    <com.example.myapplication.CustomView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </com.example.myapplication.CustomView>









</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The expected result is: the constructor of the view is executed one time
Actual Result: the constructor of the view is executed two times!

Comment: "the constructor of the view is executed two times!" -- that is because you are creating two instances of the `CustomView`.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a breakpoint in the constructor to examine the call stack and to learn where it is called exactly.

The first invocation comes from `setContentView` when the layout containing your custom view is inflated.

The second invocation is your explicit constructor call `new CustomView(...)` in your activity code.